# Parse XML Response from SOAP Call using Service Reference C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I am developing my first .NET ASMX Web Service project using C#. Right now I am consuming a SOAP request and attempting to parse the response. I am using Visual Studio's (2017) Service Reference to call the methods I need from a remote URL.

My issue is that despite being able to make the POST request work, I cannot figure out how I parse/read the response sent back from the server in question.

Below is the code from my .NET Project. Please help.

```
using System.Web.Services;
using HelloWorldWebService.SOAPService;

namespace HelloWorldWebService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public void HelloWorld()
        {
            //creates object that allows to invoke posts
            PostServiceSoapClient soap = new PostServiceServiceSoapClient();
             //statement that invokes SOAP post to consume service
            soap.CreateSoapPost("param1", "param2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to create the POST?

Comment: @jdweng I am using .Net C# and this is the statement soap.CreateSoapPost("param1", "param2");